# How can I stop Bootstrap Nuget Package from affecting the HTML box height

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a final project for my ASP.NET MVC class. To summarize the application, it is a hotel management system that allows users to reserve a hotel room.

I am using the bootstrap Nuget package to supply to CSS styling, but after troubleshooting, I discovered it is causing issues with sizing of the box model.

I am working on the administration panel, where a system administrator can login to perform administration tasks; such as review reservations, view user data, etc. When I view the page, the width is fit to the screen, but the height is very short, it seems to render to 1366x215.5, while I expect it to fill the display. Its worth noting that I am using an Entity Framework controller (with the pre-generated views), so rather than redirect from the administrator page to the EF controller, I am using an IFrame to display the EF Views from the Admin Controller.

When I remove the link to the bootstrap.min.css from the parent view, leaving the bootstrap link in the view displayed by the IFrame, everything works nicely. So I imagine its related to an issue when the parent uses the bootstrap.min.css file. I have tried reversing it, where I remove the link from the IFrame view, and keep it inside the parent view, but it still happens then.

Seems to be 100% caused by the bootstrap link in the parent view, but I use it all over my application and have no issues anywhere else.

Here is a photo of what is being displayed:

[image: Here is a photo of what is being displayed]

I use a master layout for my administrator pages:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>ReserveIt | @ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand">ReserveIt</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Users", "Main", "Admin", null, new { @class = "nav-link" })
                </li>
                @if (Session["email"] != null)
                {
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        @Html.ActionLink("My Account", "Details", "Accounts", new { id = Session["userID"] }, new { @class = "nav-link" })
                    </li>
                }
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="reservations.php">Reservations</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                @if (Session["email"] == null)
                {
                    @Html.ActionLink("Login", "Index", "Login", null, new { @class = "btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" });
                }
                else
                {
                    @Html.ActionLink("Logout", "Logout", "Login", null, new { @class = "btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" });
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

I currently only have the layout reference and the IFrame tags in the parent view

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Main";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminMasterLayout.cshtml";
}

<iframe src="@Url.Action("Index", "Accounts")"></iframe>
```

And the EF Controller view (the view displayed in the IFrame) is as follows

```
@model IEnumerable<ReserveIt.Models.User>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Firstname)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Middlename)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Lastname)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Phone)
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Firstname)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Middlename)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Lastname)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Phone)
            </td>
            <td style="white-space: nowrap">
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.UserID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.UserID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.UserID })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

I am relatively new to ASP.NET, so I am likely missing something and am excited to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can resolve this issue.

First it is always recommended in BootStrap to wrap an iframe in embed-responsive tag and set an aspect ratio.  For example :

See: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/embed/

Though more for you purposes and the way you have things setup it might be more advisable to just set the height of the iframe via a CSS styling yourself say 80vh (or 80% of vertical height of screen ).

Unfortunately a few thoughts and design considerations when using frames that you make wish to take into account.  The major issue with and iframe is that you cannot exactly how the content in the frame will render on each device to account for screen real estate, font size, spacing, etc. that user will have or how much content will ultimately be needed for iframe to display so ultimately using iframes will end up with extra spacing to account for these differences, and may or may not end up messing theme of your design.  Or will be too small for content and therefore may need scrollbars and therefore may present usability issues to the user.

Comment: I used the Element Inspection tool on Firefox and found that when specifying height: 100% for the frame does not have an effect, but using 100vh works great.

I noticed that the vertical size of the HTML box is very short, is that because it renders only to fit the initial content of the screen? If so, what makes the 'vh' unit capable of extending the borders of the HTML box?

Comment: On a related note. I am using an IFrame for the purpose of reducing the amount of repeated code. The admin panel has its own controller, so I saw redirecting to the EF controller for each section (users, reservations, etc) as a violation off the separation of control feature of MVC, as the admin controller would only exist to redirect to another controller. Or could copy and paste the actions from the EF controllers into the Admin controller, but I would need to put ALL of them inside and it would be exact copies of their originals.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: For HTML Height 100% is in my opinion is nearly useless as with the nearly unlimited number of screen sizes browser just do not respect that setting.  Vertical Height (vh) however does work as the systems are able to detect the vertical height of the window  and just set the feature to that height which is what 100% should do but doesn't.  .

Comment: As to controllers I understand your desire for separation of concerns and control however I would tend towards the idea of administrative controller being thin and maybe as simple as single welcome page and then redirected to other features, modules or controllers or what have you.  It could however also perform a lot of other features for controlling the admin as well what ever the ultimate version it takes.  This approach would I believe provide much better approach and use experience than the current I-framed approach while maintaining the overall separation of functionality you want.

Comment: Sounds good to me, I will definitely go give that a try. Thank you for your help, I learned a lot.